# on:animationend can't access bind:this svelte (undefined)

Tags: javascript, css, dom-events, svelte

I wanted to use `querySelector()` but I find that Svelte has another way to do this.

by using `bind:this`

---

the problem is that sometimes it works, but the most of time it will never work

by outputting `undefined`

#### here is a simple example:

```html
<script>
  let thisDiv;

  console.log(thisDiv) // ❌ "undefined" ✅ "<div>"
</script>

<div bind:this={thisDiv}>hello world</div>
```

---

#### the real bug

but the real problem is here

> because I don't need to `console.log` for now
>
> the things I wrote before are only for making you understand the bug
>
>  so I can start putting more information.

because I have a **function** that uses that variable

 and call the function when the event "`on:animationend`" starts.

like this:

```html
<div
  bind:this={thisDiv}
  on:animationend={doStuff()}
></div>
```

the problem is that `animationend` still console.log the `thisDiv` `undefined`

#### maybe is a problem of speed?

yes, ok...

but the animation in CSS only is 50ms long. and also tried with 0.5s

and CSS doesn't block the javascript, so js will continue to work when CSS is doing his animations (from what I know)

and 0.5s I think is a lot for doing a simple `bind:this` (querySelector)

**how is it even possible?** half second for getting a normal querySelector and still nothing.

[image]

---

#### source code

here the REPL online svelte source code example:

https://svelte.dev/repl/b49d019ce7f8426b80295158b091520f?version=3.50.1

> make sure to uncomment the line 9 in child.svelte

...or see this directly

**App.svelte**

```html
<script>
    import Child from "./Child.svelte"
    
    function generateExample() {
        let output = [];
        
        for(let i=0; i<=100; i++) {
            output = [
                ...output, `text ${i}`
            ]
        }
        
        return output;
    }
    
  let array = generateExample()
</script>

{#each array as item, index}
   <Child {index}>
      {item}
   </Child>
{/each}
```

**Child.svelte**

```html
<script>
  export let index;
  const DELAY = 50;
  
  let thisDiv;

    // UNCOMMENT THE NEXT LINE
  function doStuff() {
         // thisDiv.scrollIntoView(); 
  }
</script>

<div
  style="--delay:{index * DELAY}ms;"
  bind:this={thisDiv}
  on:animationend={doStuff()}
  >
  <slot></slot>
</div>

<style>
  div {
    animation: show var(--delay);
  }

  @keyframes show {
    from {
      translate: 100vw;
    }
    to {
      translate: 0;
    }
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, your code is just faulty, you called the handler instead of referencing it:

```
on:animationend={doStuff()}
```

Should be:

```
on:animationend={doStuff}
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/bce097ff8486434db845799c37eb6af1?version=3.50.1)

Also, you do not need `bind:this` and could use the event object:

```js
function doStuff(e) {
    e.target.scrollIntoView();
}
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/f06eaf7922694c43bac6e6cc6a961641?version=3.50.1)

Answer (score 1):

**code of the solution:**

```html
<script>
// other your code

$: if(thisDiv) {
  thisDiv.addEventListener("animationend", () => {
    thisDiv.scrollIntoView()
  })
}
</script>
```

and is also bug free, because of `if` checking and native javascript code.

---

the bug is happening because when you write `bind:this`, the value isn't available directly (but this doesn't mean is slow)

---

**so how to solve it?**

I believe that `$: if(thisDiv)` should make it work.

so put all the logic inside the `IF`

---

this means also that you need to not use the attribute `on:animationend` anymore since it isn't inside the `IF`

---

so we reversed the logic,

- first, we make sure that the bind isn't undefined,
- then we use **vanilla javascript** to do the logic (instead of svelte logic)

---

##### EDIT:

I saw now that @H.B suggest an easier way, because your bug was only in a typo

❌ `doStuff()` ✅ `doStuff`

Answer (score 0):

<strike>The problem is that `animationend` is fired immediately.</strike> See my other answer.

Try just logging the index/time:

```js
function doStuff() {
    console.log(index, 'end', new Date());
}
```

Would recommend adding the event listener in `onMount` (from `'svelte'`) and clean it up again on destroy:

```js
onMount(() => {
    thisDiv.addEventListener('animationend', doStuff);
    
    () => thisDiv.removeEventListener('animationend', doStuff);
})
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/b1781ddbd99c449a893aaadb7f1b407b?version=3.50.1)

Comment: thanks, what onMount does?

Comment: It runs code when the component has been created and added to the DOM, [just read the docs](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-svelte-onmount).

Comment: I tried by doing `--delay:{index * DELAY + 50}ms;` so if is 0 the index it will be 50ms but still happen the bug, so 50ms I think is enought too for attribute version (so maybe it isn't the firing immediately problem)